# How to make grid view options for dropdown select on html css vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, vue-multiselect

The dropdown options have an option with one column. I want to make it looks alike grid view selection.
[image: This is what to make it looks like.]

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with CSS flexbox.

E.g

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Read more about flexbox on https://w3schools.com